# Include <sstream> not found compile error in Xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx358.png)I have to use  in my project, but when I try to include  to my cpp file. The complier show error "'sstream' file not found"

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: OK now show the complete compiler line from the Build Log

Comment: OK good.  I cannot see much wrong with that except you are using a somewhat archaic version of C++ (`libstdc++` and `gnu98` standard).  What happens if you try `libc++` and C++03 or C++11?

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe, I can build successfully after change to "libc++"